# Sorting in XSLT not working

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to sort accounts in my original XML based on the balance which is an element in account. The code which i wrote isn't working, can't figure out why. I think it's correct. Can you please help me where I might be wrong?

Here is the part of my original XML file.

```
<account actype="Current" acid="ac_10100001234" branch-id="br_101" cid="c_100101">
    <open-date>25/5/2013</open-date>
    <close-date>31/03/2015</close-date>
    <balance>5000</balance>
</account>
<account actype="Saving" acid="ac_10100002123" branch-id="br_101" cid="c_100101">
    <open-date>12/5/2012</open-date>
    <close-date>12/11/2014</close-date>
    <balance>8000</balance>
</account>
<account actype="Recurring" acid="ac_12051001" branch-id="br_1205" cid="c_100102">
    <open-date>22/5/2014</open-date>
    <close-date>21/5/2019</close-date>
    <balance>4200</balance>
</account>
<account actype="Fixed" acid="ac_1012052113" branch-id="br_101" cid="c_100102">
    <open-date>20/10/2009</open-date>
    <close-date>19/10/2014</close-date>
    <balance>100000</balance>
</account>
<account actype="Current" acid="ac_100100001234" branch-id="br_1100" cid="c_1001100">
    <open-date>15/5/2010</open-date>
    <close-date>12/4/2014</close-date>
    <balance>300</balance>
</account>
```

This shows how I call my template on accounts.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/Bank">
    <root>
      <name>
        <xsl:value-of select="name" />
      </name>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="branch" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="employee" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="customer" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="account" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="transaction" />
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="account">
    <xsl:for-each select=".">
      <xsl:sort select="balance" />
      <Account>
        <AccountNumber>
          <xsl:value-of select="@acid" />
        </AccountNumber>
        <Customerid>
          <xsl:value-of select="@cid" />
        </Customerid>
        <balance>
          <xsl:value-of select="balance" />
        </balance>
      </Account>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It is wrong. Show us the complete XSLT. You've `xsl:sort` inside `xsl:for-each` in `xsl:template`. The template is called once for every match, and you are trying to sort only the current match. It shall be on the `xsl:apply-templates` from where the template is called, if you've any.

Comment: I used xsl:for-each cause u have to write sort inside either for-each or apply-templates.

Comment: And, which is the wrong way of doing it.. The `xsl:template` is called once for each `account`, and having  an `xsl:for-each` inside the template implies that you're sorting the current `account` the template is working on, which is as good as not having a for-each. I suggest you to post your complete XSLT here.

Comment: ok i got what you are saying. But then what should i do. Go to the parent element while calling the template..??

Comment: And yeah i put my xslt showing how m i calling my account template. I am calling other templates as well, but didn't put them here coz stack overflow  is asking me to edit/indent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve sorted output you need to *apply the templates* in a certain order. A template cannot sort itself.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/Bank">
    <root>
      <xsl:copy-of select="name" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="branch" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="employee" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="customer" />
      <!-- here! -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="account">
        <xsl:sort select="balance" data-type="number" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="transaction" />
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="account">
    <Account>
      <AccountNumber>
        <xsl:value-of select="@acid" />
      </AccountNumber>
      <Customerid>
        <xsl:value-of select="@cid" />
      </Customerid>
      <xsl:copy-of select="balance" />
    </Account>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note

- The `data-type`. This defaults to "string", which won't sort numbers correctly.
- `<xsl:copy-of>`
- You don't seem to use the `xs` namespace, you could remove the declaration.